# Get the bounds of the visible part of a map?

Tags: d3.js, maps

Is there is a way to get the bounds (in svg coords) of only the visible part of a map, especially after zooming/panning?

Thanks,
Arnaud

Comment: That would be the bounds of the container element, no?

Comment: What if the container is not rectangular?
I put an example here to be more specific: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b78ypxf9/).
If I zoom and pan on the edge of the map, container's coordinates are not defined outside the map (due to the chosen projection). Should I create an additionnal rectangular container that encapsulates the map? Thx

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you're trying to achieve. What do you actually want to do?

Comment: I have the idea of achieving an adaptative graticule (with labels) depending on the zoom level. For that, I have to know exactly were I am located on the map (which means determine the boundaries of the displayed part of the map). I suppose this also may be useful to generate a "minimap" (whole unzoomed map with the visible part displayed in a box). Does it make sense?

Comment: Ok, but then you know that the entire map fits if the corner coordinates are not defined.

Comment: Not necessarily. If you try zooming the map center, at some point, all corners are still outside the map, but the map is cropped.

Comment: Would you need to adjust the graticule in this case?

Comment: Hum...probably not, since the map is not so zoomed.

Comment: To simplyfy, when zooming, I suppose I need to redraw the graticule (with smaller steps) but just in the displayed area (for performance issue? not sure about that, I need to try) with the associated labels. Do you know how can I achieve this elegantly?

Comment: It seems to me that you can just redraw the graticule depending on the zoom level, regardless of where you are. I don't think that this will be significantly less efficient as the browser will only redraw the visible part anyway.

Comment: Ok. I will try that and test if there is any performance issue. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Redrawing the graticule does not impact the performance (see: http://jsfiddle.net/vtL7c0ov/). Now, I would like to know how to label this graticule. For the moment, the labels are adapted to the full map view (i.e. on the axis). Is there a way to have labels when the map is zoomed and when the axis are not visible? Thanks!

Comment: Not easily I guess, you'd probably want to modify the graticule code to draw the labels.

Comment: In order to label the graticule (when the map is zoomed enough), the first idea I had was to calculate the intersection between the graticule (and graticule outline) and the displayed part of the map (rectangle) with this library : https://github.com/thelonious/js-intersections. Knowing the intersection(s), I can label the map. So back to my first question, how do I retrieve the coordinates of the displayed part of the map (my rectangle)?

Comment: Use the projection to map the points.

Comment: I am sorry, but which points are you talking about?

Comment: The points of the rectangle, as we've discussed earlier.

Comment: Now, I think I am lost in my own topic (too much related reading I suppose). Do you mean the rectangular container of the map (the viewport if I am not wrong)?

Comment: If you want to know what fits into the rectangular container, take the corner coordinates of the container and inverse project them to get map coordinates.

Comment: OK, but how do I retrieve the container coordinates?

Comment: Well at some point you added the container to the page at a specific place with specific dimensions. The upper left corner is (0,0) and the bottom right whatever the size is.

Comment: At the start, corners coordinates are easy to get. But what about after zooming and panning?

Comment: The SVG coordinates of the corners do not change.

Comment: If coordinates do not change, so do the projected ones. I think there is something fundamental I do not get. That would be very nice of you if you could help me by adapting this example: http://jsfiddle.net/kwh04gvk/1/. In the meantime, I will also try to figure this out on my own. Thanks a lot Lars!

Comment: They do change as you zoom in. You can see this in your example.